# Python input error NameError on running script env

Tags: python

(Python3) I have created a mini script to remember unknown words but I've a little problem, maybe it's easy to solve.

The script works perfectly when I execute it with the "Python Script.py" but when I try to execute it with the "install" script in / usr / local / bin changing the header with "#!/usr/bin/env python "I get the following error:

> English word: Word Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/local/bin/trans", line 95, in "module"
>
> ```
> word = input("English word: ")
> ```
>
> File "string", line 1, in "module"
>
> NameError: name 'Word' is not defined

I use word = input ('English word:') to store the option.

So, when I set the input like:

`Englis word: Example`

I got the error, but when I enclosed in quotation marks like:

`English word: 'Example'`

It works perfect, but why? What's the explanation? And a solution to avoid to add " ' ' "?

Just in case I use Ubuntu.

Beforehand thanks for reading!

Comment: Use `raw_input()`, or install Python 3 if you are following a tutorial that is telling you to use `input()`.

Comment: I'm using Python3 for that reason i don't use raw_input().

Comment: No, the behaviour you described is Python 2 *only*, not Python 3.

Comment: It's solved, the problem was that i have python 2.x by default, thanks Pieters.